# Jira query is not working in JIRA search?

Tags: jql

I am using JIRA version v8.5.9, where I am running the following query in its search option.

```
issuetype = "bug" AND assigned == 'xyz'
```

Where `xyz` is a user. Basically I what I am trying to achieve is: I am looking for sub-tasks for all stories whose assignee is `xyz` and `abc` users. When I am running this query it's not giving me any results. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use following query in search option: Which will look for all sub-tasks for specific users named `xyz`, `abc`.

```
issuetype = "Sub task"  AND assignee in (xyz,abc)
```

***Explanation:***

- Look for Sub task field first.
- Then look for assignees which are multiple in this condition, abc and xyz in your samples.